# HTML bizarre rendering of my javascript function call?

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following error in the big three (IE, Chrome, FF):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

When I look at the rendered html in dev tools I see this:

```
<div style="...">
  <a style="..." onclick="LaunchTemplateBrowser(" href="#" false;'="" 'x_project');return="" c74767f5-6ce4-4975-9778-e4f9ad1e5ded',="">
    <img style="..." src="...">
  </a>
  <span style="...">Add from template</span>
  <br><br>
  <a style="..." onclick="LaunchItemInsert();return false;" href="#">
    <img style="..." src="...">
  </a>
  <span style="color: rgb(139, 139, 139);">Add single item</span>
</div>
```

The important lines above are 2 and 7. On line 2 I am passing a guid and that seems to be throwing it for a loop?

The source code is:

```
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>﻿   
    <title></title>

    <div style="...">
        <div style="...">
            <a href="#" style="..." onclick="LaunchTemplateBrowser('C74767F5-6CE4-4975-9778-E4F9AD1E5DED', 'x_project');return false;" >
            <img style="..." src="..." />
            </a>
            <span style="...">Add from template</span>
            <br /><br />
            <a href="#" style="..." onclick='LaunchItemInsert();return false;' >
                <img style="..." src="..." />
            </a>
            <span style="...">Add single item</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the quotes before using them.

Either by prefixing them with `\` or using a combination of single and double quotes.

Comment: So is there no absolute like c# where you can use @"..."

Comment: No. You don't have that sort of thing in javascript